# Right-click doesn't update ItemIndex in TControlList

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I've added a `TPopupMenu` to a `TControlList`, on right-click the ItemIndex isn't updated to reflect the item clicked on.  Is there a way to make a right-click respond in a similar way to a left-click?

This would be nice so that the user right-clicks on a particular item, the PopupMenu is associated with that item, not the currently focused item.

Comment: You would probably need to introduce new property similar to [`TTreeView.RightClickSelect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeView.RightClickSelect). To implement that just handle selection change in `WM_CONTEXTMENU`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HotItemIndex` property can be used to detect which item has been right-clicked by using the following

```
procedure TListingList.clListingsMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  if Button <> mbRight then
    Exit;

  if clListings.HotItemIndex <> -1 then
    clListings.ItemIndex := clListings.HotItemIndex;
end;
```

This mostly works, but if you already have a `TPopupmenu` visible already, then the `HotItemIndex` is `-1`.  This means that consecutive right-clicks don't popup for the correct item - but I can live with this.  I think a `MousePosToItemIndex` or `ItemIndexUnderMouse` method would be required to fix this properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HotItemIndex property from OnPopupMenu event and save it to a variable. Then for the popup menu items events you can use it.

Example code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.ControlList, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ControlList1: TControlList;
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    TestPopupMnu: TMenuItem;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure ControlList1BeforeDrawItem(AIndex: Integer; ACanvas: TCanvas; ARect:
        TRect; AState: TOwnerDrawState);
    procedure ControlList1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TestPopupMnuClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PopupMenu1Popup(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FPopupItemIndex : Integer;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ControlList1BeforeDrawItem(AIndex: Integer; ACanvas: TCanvas;
    ARect: TRect; AState: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
    Label1.Caption := AIndex.ToString;
end;

procedure TForm1.ControlList1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Clicked item ' + ControlList1.ItemIndex.ToString);
end;

procedure TForm1.TestPopupMnuClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Test PopupMenu item ' + FPopupItemIndex.ToString);
end;

procedure TForm1.PopupMenu1Popup(Sender: TObject);
begin
    FPopupItemIndex := ControlList1.HotItemIndex;
end;

end.
```

The form itself:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 299
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ControlList1: TControlList
    Left = 24
    Top = 20
    Width = 317
    Height = 200
    ItemCount = 5
    ItemMargins.Left = 0
    ItemMargins.Top = 0
    ItemMargins.Right = 0
    ItemMargins.Bottom = 0
    ParentColor = False
    PopupMenu = PopupMenu1
    TabOrder = 0
    OnBeforeDrawItem = ControlList1BeforeDrawItem
    OnClick = ControlList1Click
    object Label1: TLabel
      Left = 92
      Top = 20
      Width = 31
      Height = 13
      Caption = 'Label1'
    end
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Left = 368
    Top = 24
    Width = 241
    Height = 201
    Lines.Strings = (
      'Memo1')
    TabOrder = 1
  end
  object PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu
    OnPopup = PopupMenu1Popup
    Left = 436
    Top = 128
    object TestPopupMnu: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Test'
      OnClick = TestPopupMnuClick
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think using the HotItemIndex property is what I'm after

Answer (score 2):

In order to handle Right Clicks you will have to make use of `OnMouseDown` or `OnMouseUp` events instead of `OnClick` event.

Unlike `OnClick` event that only detects left clicks `OnMouseDown` and `OnMouseUp` events are able to detect all mouse clicks (left, right, middle).

```
procedure TForm1.ControlList1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button = mbRight then
  begin
    //Do what needs to be done on right click
  end
  else if Button = mbMiddle then
  begin
    //Do what needs to be done on middle click
  end
end;
```